# How to store selected language in local storage Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I need to store selected language in local storage. This Is my task:

**After page initialization check if the user selected language before, if yes -> set selected language as default, if no -> use browser language, if there is no browser language in supported list use default ('en').**

And this is my code

```
public languages = [{
    name: 'English',
    code: 'en',
    icon: 'assets/images/flags/en.png'
}, {
    name: 'French',
    code: 'fr',
    icon: 'assets/images/flags/fr.png'
}, {
    name: 'Русский',
    code: 'ru',
    icon: 'assets/images/flags/ru.png'
}];

this.selectedLanguage = this.languages.find(lang => lang.code === this.translate.defaultLang);

changeLanguage(language) {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
        this.translate.use(language.code);
    }
    this.selectedLanguage = language;
}
```

Comment: Just use `localStorage.setItem('lang', language)`

Comment: No need to do anything  with angular. Just use `localstorage.setItem('name',language)`. To retrieve use localstorage.getItem ('name')`. Note: localstorage only stores as string, so use JSON.stringify and JSON.parse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add something to localstorage you can just do `localStorage.setItem('selectedLanguage', JSON.stringify(language))`